# Rendering "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" as a sibling to React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very large table I need to be able to render.  I've picked 1000 x 1000 as my upper end scalability test.  Most of the time the users won't be rendering a table this big, but occasionally they need to and they don't want a "paging" model and I haven't found an infinite table that meets my needs.

Rendering each cell as a React `<td>` blows up (not suprising - that's a lot of components!)

I don't *really* need to manage every `<td>` as a React component, so I'm using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in a `<tr>` component.  That works well enough.

Right now it is defined as `<tr dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html_cols} />`

I'd like to have a single left-most `<td>` in the `<tr>` be a React component, and then the rest be `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

I could use `<tr><td>row header</td><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html_cols} /></tr>`, but it seems wrong to put `<td>`'s in a `<div>`.

Ideally I'd like some kind of virtual/null component that is allowed to have inner html, but emits no enclosing markup.

edit:

I'm open to other suggestions, too, as I realize I'd have to sanitize my inputs manually.  At the moment I'm also looking at `renderToStaticMarkup` to see if I could still use React, but just not have the virtual dom overhead for some nodes.

Comment: Would something like "React Virtualized" help: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized This renders only the visible components into the DOM, changing that as you scroll.

Comment: That looks super promising -- It didn't show up in my earlier searches.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MattHolland I think what I'm going to end up using instead is embedding DataTables.js and using its deferred rendering plugin.

Answer (score 0):

After learning more about how React works, I believe what I am asking for is a React Node that is text only with no DOM node associated with it.

But React Node's are virtual DOM nodes -- it does not appear you can have a React Node without an associated DOM node, so what I wanted is not possible.